# How to prevent command execution edited with fc

Tags: command-line, bash, vim

I have `FCEDIT` set to `vim`. If I call `fc` command it will open `vim` with temporary file and contents of that file will be the last executed command from history.

The problem is that even if I exit without saving, the command still gets executed. For instance:

```
$ printf "\nHelloAskubuntu\n\n"

HelloAskubuntu

$ fc # opens vim, I do :q!
printf "\nHelloAskubuntu\n\n"

HelloAskubuntu
```

How do I avoid that ?

Comment: In the editor, enter `dd:x`.  That will delete the line and save an empty file.  That way there is not command to execute.

Comment: Is there any better approach than manually deleting a line ?

Comment: @Serg It’s the standard approach in Subversion and Git [commit message editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146907/git-abort-commit-in-the-middle-of-typing-message), for example. However, you need to delete the whole file. Do it using `dG`. A one-line file is a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fc` will not execute the command if the editor command did not exit successfully. In Vim, [there's a command for forcing this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/controlling-vim-s-exit-status-td1167370.html): [`:cq`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acq):

```
                                                        :cq :cquit
:cq[uit][!]             Quit Vim with an error code, so that the compiler
                        will not compile the same file again.
                        WARNING: All changes in files are lost!  Also when the
                        [!] is not used.  It works like ":qall!" :qall,
                        except that Vim returns a non-zero exit code.
```

So, when you don't feel like running the command, use `:cq` to quit instead of `:q!`. It might be possible to make Vim do this if you didn't make any changes, but that will probably be more annoying to get to work reliably than just using `:cq`.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because the contents are already stored in the temporary file `/tmp/bash-fc-*`. Closing it directly, `fc` will run that shell anyway.

A working approach that I could test it in Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Create a proxy command (new editor)

   ```
   sudo vim /usr/local/bin/vim2
   ```

   Make it open that file in `vim` then empty it on disc. So the contents are only in `vim` if you don't save it, `fc` will run nothing

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   sh -c "sleep 1; echo -n ''>$1" &
   vim $1
   ```

   Fix permission

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vim2
   ```
2. Set `FCEDIT` to `vim2` or temporarily to test `export FCEDIT=vim2`

The only hope is that you are not quicker than me, to close `vim` before 1 sec passed.